# Static/choppy audio when using pyjinus, kivy, AudioTrack on android?

Tags: java, android, python, audio, kivy

I created a kivy app to run on android.  I'm using pyjinius to communicate to native java/android language.  I'm using the AudioTrack class in order to write() streaming audio data to android device speakers.  So the code basically works like this:  Thread is created to set up AudioTrack class with proper variables, I then play() the AudioTrack [originally I had one thread for this, but i guess play() is blocking in python?? so I just made two threads], then I start a new thread which loops to collect socket.recv() data from peer, then gets rms(audio level) of data [this works fine], then write() audio data to the AudioTrack stream to output sound to speakers.   It seems to work, but it's static-y / choppy audio - like a screeching noise.  Is there something wrong with the AudioTrach set-up that is doing this?  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
class ReceiveVoiceThread(Thread):
# Receive Voice Data

    def __init__(self, sock, name, pop):
        # Called on creation
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = sock
        self.name = name
        self.pop = pop

    def run(self):

        sample = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(
            AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE
        )

        if not sample:
            sample = 44100

        n = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
            sample,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, # 8 Bit for byte array data
        )
        # n = 1024


        self.audio_stream = AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE,
            sample,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, # 8 Bit for byte array data
            n, # bufsizbytes,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
        )
        self.audio_stream.play()

        audio_thread = AudioThread(self.audio_stream, n, self.sock, self.name, self.pop)
        audio_thread.start()


class AudioThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, audio_stream, n, sock, name, pop):
        # Called on creation
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = sock
        self.name = name
        self.pop = pop
        self.audio_stream = audio_stream
        self.n = n

    def run(self):

        while True:
            try:
                data = self.sock.recv(self.n)

                rms = self.get_rms(data, self.n)

                if rms > 400:
                    App.get_running_app().peer_speaking[self.name] = True
                else:
                    App.get_running_app().peer_speaking[self.name] = False


                # write(byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes, int writeMode)
                self.audio_stream.write(data, 0, self.n, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING)
            except:
                pass



        self.audio_stream.flush()
        self.audio_stream.stop() 
        self.audio_stream.release() 


    def get_rms(self, buff_array, n):
        s = 0
        count = len(buff_array)/2
        integers = struct.unpack('H'*count, buff_array)
        for i in integers:
            s += i*i
        rms = (s/len(integers))**(1/2.0)
        return rms
```

Comment: try `WRITE_BLOCKING`

Comment: I actually figured out that the incoming socket data was 32bit audio [I have a linux machine using pyaudio to write streaming data from my linux mic].  I changed the incoming data to 16bit audio (short array for android?) by using the setting: pyaudio.paInt16 rather than pyaudio.paInt32.   The only issue with the above code is the get_rms() function; but the code works fine without that function.  I'm sure WRITE_BLOCKING would work too.  Thanks

Comment: Let me just add that WRITE_BLOCKING certainly helps the quality.   So thanks for that.